# MS Access query: #Error in Switch Function - Format issue

Tags: ms-access

I'm making a query that JOIN to table, A and B.
A contains below fields:
   TAP - Short Text (AAAA, BBBB, etc)
   Operator - Short Text
   Zone - Short Text (Zone 01, Zone 02..)
B contains below one:
   TAP - Short Text
   MCC - Number (20210, 20032, etc)

My query is:

```
SELECT A.TAP, A.Operator, SWITCH(B.MCC='10020', 'Own Network', B.MCC, A.Zone) FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.TAP=B.TAP
```

Query result shows #Error value for all Zone values. I think that this is due to MCC is in Number format, because, when I change MCC to Short Text (althought there is not text, only number), the query dumps the correct Zone.. but I cannot change, because I have to use MCC in Number format for other queries.

TAP | Operator | Zone  | MCC
AAAA | ATT | Zone 01 |  120001
BBBB |  Two | Own Network | 10020

Any suggestion? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really getting that `SWITCH` statement. The third argument (`B.MCC`) should evaluate to a boolean, and it doesn't.

Use `IIF(Nz(B.MCC)=10020, 'Own Network', A.Zone)`. I believe that's what you intend to do.

Other problems fixed:

- MCC is a number, `'10020'` a string. Removed apostrophes to make `10020` a number
- MCC contained empty (`Null`) values. Used `Nz` to cast these values to `0`

Comment: Thanks. I had also tried IIF statement, but is not working neither.. result is the same, #Error  in Zone field when there is MCc and Zone 01 or any value different to #Error when MCC is blank.

Comment: Many thanks Erik. Now is working. And Zone dumps the values that I want. So, how Nz works? does it return a string?

Comment: See edit for a short explanation. If it worked, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per Erik suggestion, issue was resolved removing apostrophes to the number and addiding Nz in order to cast empty values to Zero.